# FLIR PTU initialization error

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I'm trying to get a FLIR pan and tilt unit (PTU) to run. I've cloned the following repo's:

```
https://github.com/wjwwood/serial.git
https://github.com/ros-drivers/flir_ptu.git
```

My username has been added to the dialup group. I've checked that the device is on and connected (dmesg | grep tty). I made sure the baud rate is correct. I tried launching it with the delivered launch file:

```
roslaunch flir_ptu_driver ptu.launch
```

But unfortunately I get:

```
SUMMARY
========

PARAMETERS
 * /ptu/ptu_driver/port: /dev/ttyUSB0
 * /robot_description: <?xml version="1....
 * /rosdistro: indigo
 * /rosversion: 1.11.21

NODES
  /ptu/
    ptu_driver (flir_ptu_driver/ptu_node)
  /
    robot_state_publisher (robot_state_publisher/state_publisher)

auto-starting new master
process[master]: started with pid [21768]
ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311

setting /run_id to 6da03ef4-3956-11e7-be4f-8c89a57cea6f
process[rosout-1]: started with pid [21781]
started core service [/rosout]
process[robot_state_publisher-2]: started with pid [21785]
process[ptu/ptu_driver-3]: started with pid [21798]
[ERROR] [1494842903.849068048]: Error getting pan-tilt res
[ERROR] [1494842904.052991450]: Error getting pan-tilt res
[ERROR] [1494842904.257020561]: Error getting pan-tilt limit
[ERROR] [1494842904.460998246]: Error getting pan-tilt limit
[ERROR] [1494842904.664990558]: Error getting pan-tilt limit
[ERROR] [1494842904.868993172]: Error getting pan-tilt limit
[ERROR] [1494842905.072993043]: Error getting pan-tilt limit
[ERROR] [1494842905.276940833]: Error getting pan-tilt limit
[ERROR] [1494842905.480866315]: Error getting pan-tilt limit
[ERROR] [1494842905.684846684]: Error getting pan-tilt limit
[ERROR] [1494842905.684931517]: Could not initialize FLIR PTU on /dev/ttyUSB0
```

I can't figure out what else I could try from here to get it to run. Has anyone got any suggestions or has anyone had the same issue?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/261756/flir-ptu-initialization-error/) by [alexandru.lesi](https://answers.ros.org/users/30212/alexandru.lesi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2017-05-15

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The /dev/ttyUSB0 port belongs to the group **dialout** so you need to add the user to that group as follows:

```
sudo adduser $USER dialout
```

---

Originally posted by [jrgnicho](https://answers.ros.org/users/22410/jrgnicho/) with karma: 486 on 2017-05-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [alexandru.lesi](https://answers.ros.org/users/30212/alexandru.lesi/) on 2017-05-15**:
Like I mentioned in my description my username has already been added to the dialup group

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-05-15**:
Just making sure: you have logged out and logged in after adding yourself to the group? What is the output of `ls -al /dev/ttyUSB0` and `groups`?